# SQL query to display names of all employees who do NOT have a phone?

Tags: sql

Consider an `Employee` table with 2 columns

ID which is of INT datatype

NAME which is of VARCHAR datatype.

Consider a second `Employee_PHONE` table with 2 columns

ID which is of INT datatype

PHONE which is of VARCHAR datatype. 
Both are set to NOT NULL.

ID of EMPLOYEE_PHONE is a foreign key which references the primary key of EMPLOYEE table

An employee may not have any phone or may have multiple phones. 
What will be the SQL query to display names of all employees who do NOT have a phone ?

Comment: What database system are you using? Oracle, SQL Server, Postgresql, MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

This can be translated directly from "english to SQL"

```
select e.*
from employee e ---<<< get me all employees 
where not exists ---<<< that do not have a phone
          (select *  
           from employee_phone ep
           where ep.employee_id = e.id
             and ep.phone <> ''); -- in case you allow empty strings in that column
```

Comment: It can be exists but the phone column is blank.. so this query will not include that blank phone numbers if the same id exists in two tables.

Comment: @JapzDivino: well the column is set to `NOT NULL` so I assume that an "empty string" is also not valid, but I have update the query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Maybe `ISNULL(ep.phone.'') <> ''` would be better?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu: the `isnull()` is not necessary because the column is defined as `NOT NULL`  thus it can not contain `NULL` values

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu: if at all, something like `trim(ep.phone)` would be needed to also catch values that only contain blanks

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , oh i miss that `NOT NULL` one.. if that is the case, your code above will work perfectly, i will modify my answer too :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's two choices query.

```
    SELECT * FROM Employee a WHERE a.ID NOT IN (SELECT b.ID FROM Employee_PHONE)

    SELECT * FROM Employee a 
    LEFT JOIN Employee_PHONE b ON a.ID = b.ID WHERE ISNULL(b.PHONE,'') = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select E.Name 
from Employee E left Join Employee_PHONE EP
     on E.ID = EP.ID
where EP.EMPLOYEE_PHONE is null or EP.EMPLOYEE_PHONE = ''
```

Comment: `INNER JOIN` would show only employees with phone numbers. OP wants the opposite. Maybe you're looking for a different type of `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select E.Name 
from Employee E left Join Employee_PHONE EP
     on E.ID = EP.ID
where EP.EMPLOYEE_PHONE is null
```